# Removing a specific item from the cache

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc-4, browser-cache

Is this possible? Scenario: I have a multi-part form where each part other than the first starts off hidden, then gets displayed one by one upon completion of the last. Each form has its own error messages that are shown upon failure.

A form's `post` action always redirects to its relevant `get` one. If the user enters something invalid, it does so with persistence of the `ModelState` through `TempData`.

The problem is that the persisted `ModelState` isn't getting cleared when I hit the back button. This means that the error message is still shown--I would like it to be cleared. I'm thinking that I can accomplish that by clearing out specifically the cached ModelState--I need other items to continue being cached so I can't just use the `[OutputCache]` attribute. Do I use `Cache.Remove()`? Would the key name for it be the same as what I've passed into the `TempData`, and where would I put that call?